# How to edit Dynamic row data in jqxgrid codebehind

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, jqwidget

I use **Jqxgrid** to show my dynamic data in that my last column there is Edit Button for each row. I need to perform particular row edit on click of edit button.

I use Datatable and smartgridboundfields to show the data in jqxgrid.

how can i perform this type of functionality?

string html = "";

```
            html += "<a id='sedit'>Edit</a>";
            html += "<a id='sdelete' style='margin-left: 10px'>Delete</a>";

            dr["Actions"] = html;
```

this code is my code behind edit button which i showing in my jqxgrid.

Answer (score 0):

In that case you can use [`beginrowedit`](http://jsfiddle.net/jqwidgets/nUc8P/):

```
$('#sedit').on('click', function () {
  // here change the 0 for the row index
  $("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid('beginrowedit', 0); 
});
```

Or [`begincelledit`](http://jsfiddle.net/jqwidgets/skzmE/):

```
$('#sedit').on('click', function () {
  // here change the 0 for the row index, 
  // and your column datafield instead of "firstname"
  $("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid('begincelledit', 0, "firstname"); 
});
```

In order to get the row index: 
`var rowindex = $('#jqxgrid').jqxGrid('getselectedrowindex');`